# Filebeat with Redis

Tags: elasticsearch, redis, filebeat

Base on elastic documentation on filebeat, plugins provided to insert events into redis via filebeat, but it`s under Redis list(file structure type).

```
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/redis-output.html
```

Just wonder if I want to insert all events in Hashes, is that possible ?

Regards,
SIMON

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for this is that the Redis list data type acts as a temporary queue that contains your data before it is consumed by some other component (logstash, etc). On the other side of the pipeline, the consuming component will simply call LPOP/BLPOP to remove the first (oldest) element from the list and process it.

A Redis hash data type is not usable as a queue, you need to ask yourself how the consumer component would be able to consume data that is stored in hashes. For instance, the Logstash `redis` input plugin allows to use either the `list`, `channel` or `pattern_channel` data type, all of which can act as a temporary queue from which consumers can get and process data.

Comment: hi @Val , correct me if i am wrong, as i really beginner on redis.
How do we use hashes ? 
https://redislabs.com/ebook/redis-in-action/part-2-core-concepts-2/chapter-3-commands-in-redis/3-4-hashes